# React Component not opening in Sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a project in my own and have a bit grasp of what I am doing and at first I had a problem that the global theme was interfering with and `Home` and `Login` component, then I had to separate it and make a new route structure. From `Home` I need to click a button and a login/sign-up page will arrive. If it's a successful log in I can go to dashboard. The dashboard page is fine and looking exactly as it should be but if I click any other component like `Team`, `Contacts`, etc, they do load but don't show anything at all. At first they all were working and now they don't.

Below is my App.js code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Topbar from "./scenes/global/Topbar";
import Dashboard from "./scenes/dashboard";
import Team from "./scenes/team";
import Invoices from "./scenes/invoices";
import Contacts from "./scenes/contacts";
import Bar from "./scenes/bar";
import Form from "./scenes/form";
import Line from "./scenes/line";
import Pie from "./scenes/pie";
import FAQ from "./scenes/faq";
import Home from "./LandingPage";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
import Geography from "./scenes/geography";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
import Calendar from "./scenes/calendar/calendar";
import SidebarComp from "./scenes/global/Sidebar";

function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<NonDashboardLayout />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/*" element={<DashboardLayout theme={theme} />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function NonDashboardLayout() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function DashboardLayout({ theme }) {
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <ColorModeContext.Provider value={theme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <SidebarComp isSidebar={isSidebar} />
          <main className="content">
            <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />
            <Routes>
              <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="team" element={<Team />} />
              <Route path="contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
              <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
              <Route path="form" element={<Form />} />
              <Route path="bar" element={<Bar />} />
              <Route path="pie" element={<Pie />} />
              <Route path="line" element={<Line />} />
              <Route path="faq" element={<FAQ />} />
              <Route path="calendar" element={<Calendar />} />
              <Route path="geography" element={<Geography />} />
            </Routes>
          </main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Since I am clicking on `Sidebar` icons to access those components that aren't working I thought to share this as well.

The Sidebar.js is:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from "react-pro-sidebar";
import { Box, IconButton, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { tokens } from "../../theme";
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined";
import PeopleOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PeopleOutlined";
import ContactsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ContactsOutlined";
import ReceiptOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ReceiptOutlined";
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined";
import CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarTodayOutlined";
import HelpOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutlineOutlined";
import BarChartOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BarChartOutlined";
import PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PieChartOutlineOutlined";
import TimelineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TimelineOutlined";
import MenuOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuOutlined";
import MapOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MapOutlined";

const Item = ({ title, to, icon, selected, setSelected }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

  return (
    <MenuItem
      active={selected === title}
      style={{
        color: colors.grey[100],
      }}
      onClick={() => setSelected(title)}
      icon={icon}
    >
      <Link to={to} style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}>
        <Typography>{title}</Typography>
      </Link>
    </MenuItem>
  );
};

const SidebarComp = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Dashboard");

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        "& .pro-sidebar-inner": {
          background: `${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
        },
        "& .pro-icon-wrapper": {
          backgroundColor: "transparent !important",
        },
        "& .pro-inner-item": {
          padding: "5px 35px 5px 20px !important",
        },
        "& .pro-inner-item:hover": {
          color: "#868dfb !important",
        },
        "& .pro-menu-item.active": {
          color: "#6870fa !important",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Sidebar collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <Menu iconShape="square">
          {/* LOGO AND MENU ICON */}
          <MenuItem
            onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
            icon={isCollapsed ? <MenuOutlinedIcon /> : undefined}
            style={{
              margin: "10px 0 20px 0",
              color: colors.grey[100],
            }}
          >
            {!isCollapsed && (
              <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
                ml="15px"
              >
                <Typography variant="h3" color={colors.grey[100]}>
                  ADMIN PANEL
                </Typography>
                <IconButton onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
                  <MenuOutlinedIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            )}
          </MenuItem>

          {!isCollapsed && (
            <Box mb="25px">
              <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <img
                  alt="profile-user"
                  width="100px"
                  height="100px"
                  src={`../../assets/user.png`}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", borderRadius: "50%" }}
                />
              </Box>
              <Box textAlign="center">
                <Typography
                  variant="h2"
                  color={colors.grey[100]}
                  fontWeight="bold"
                  sx={{ m: "10px 0 0 0" }}
                >
                  Leo Rigasaki
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" color={colors.greenAccent[500]}>
                  Admin
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          )}

          <Box paddingLeft={isCollapsed ? undefined : "10%"}>
            <Item
              title="Dashboard"
              to="/dashboard"
              icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Data
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Manage Team"
              to="/team"
              icon={<PeopleOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Contacts Information"
              to="/contacts"
              icon={<ContactsOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Invoices Balances"
              to="/invoices"
              icon={<ReceiptOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Pages
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Profile Form"
              to="/form"
              icon={<PersonOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Calendar"
              to="/calendar"
              icon={<CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="FAQ Page"
              to="/faq"
              icon={<HelpOutlineOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Charts
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Bar Chart"
              to="/bar"
              icon={<BarChartOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Pie Chart"
              to="/pie"
              icon={<PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Line Chart"
              to="/line"
              icon={<TimelineOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Geography Chart"
              to="/geography"
              icon={<MapOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
          </Box>
        </Menu>
      </Sidebar>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default SidebarComp;
```

and theme.js is:

```js
import { createContext, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

// color design tokens export
export const tokens = (mode) => ({
  ...(mode === "dark"
    ? {
        grey: {
          100: "#e0e0e0",
          200: "#c2c2c2",
          300: "#a3a3a3",
          400: "#858585",
          500: "#666666",
          600: "#525252",
          700: "#3d3d3d",
          800: "#292929",
          900: "#141414",
        },
        primary: {
          100: "#d0d1d5",
          200: "#a1a4ab",
          300: "#727681",
          400: "#1F2A40",
          500: "#141b2d",
          600: "#101624",
          700: "#0c101b",
          800: "#080b12",
          900: "#040509",
        },
        greenAccent: {
          100: "#dbf5ee",
          200: "#b7ebde",
          300: "#94e2cd",
          400: "#70d8bd",
          500: "#4cceac",
          600: "#3da58a",
          700: "#2e7c67",
          800: "#1e5245",
          900: "#0f2922",
        },
        redAccent: {
          100: "#f8dcdb",
          200: "#f1b9b7",
          300: "#e99592",
          400: "#e2726e",
          500: "#db4f4a",
          600: "#af3f3b",
          700: "#832f2c",
          800: "#58201e",
          900: "#2c100f",
        },
        blueAccent: {
          100: "#e1e2fe",
          200: "#c3c6fd",
          300: "#a4a9fc",
          400: "#868dfb",
          500: "#6870fa",
          600: "#535ac8",
          700: "#3e4396",
          800: "#2a2d64",
          900: "#151632",
        },
      }
    : {
        grey: {
          100: "#141414",
          200: "#292929",
          300: "#3d3d3d",
          400: "#525252",
          500: "#666666",
          600: "#858585",
          700: "#a3a3a3",
          800: "#c2c2c2",
          900: "#e0e0e0",
        },
        primary: {
          100: "#040509",
          200: "#080b12",
          300: "#0c101b",
          400: "#f2f0f0", // manually changed
          500: "#141b2d",
          600: "#1F2A40",
          700: "#727681",
          800: "#a1a4ab",
          900: "#d0d1d5",
        },
        greenAccent: {
          100: "#0f2922",
          200: "#1e5245",
          300: "#2e7c67",
          400: "#3da58a",
          500: "#4cceac",
          600: "#70d8bd",
          700: "#94e2cd",
          800: "#b7ebde",
          900: "#dbf5ee",
        },
        redAccent: {
          100: "#2c100f",
          200: "#58201e",
          300: "#832f2c",
          400: "#af3f3b",
          500: "#db4f4a",
          600: "#e2726e",
          700: "#e99592",
          800: "#f1b9b7",
          900: "#f8dcdb",
        },
        blueAccent: {
          100: "#151632",
          200: "#2a2d64",
          300: "#3e4396",
          400: "#535ac8",
          500: "#6870fa",
          600: "#868dfb",
          700: "#a4a9fc",
          800: "#c3c6fd",
          900: "#e1e2fe",
        },
      }),
});

// mui theme settings
export const themeSettings = (mode) => {
  const colors = tokens(mode);
  return {
    palette: {
      mode: mode,
      ...(mode === "dark"
        ? {
            // palette values for dark mode
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.greenAccent[500],
            },
            neutral: {
              dark: colors.grey[700],
              main: colors.grey[500],
              light: colors.grey[100],
            },
            background: {
              default: colors.primary[500],
            },
          }
        : {
            // palette values for light mode
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary[100],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.greenAccent[500],
            },
            neutral: {
              dark: colors.grey[700],
              main: colors.grey[500],
              light: colors.grey[100],
            },
            background: {
              default: "#fcfcfc",
            },
          }),
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
      fontSize: 12,
      h1: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 40,
      },
      h2: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 32,
      },
      h3: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 24,
      },
      h4: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 20,
      },
      h5: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 16,
      },
      h6: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
  };
};

// context for color mode
export const ColorModeContext = createContext({
  toggleColorMode: () => {},
});

export const useMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("dark");

  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () =>
        setMode((prev) => (prev === "light" ? "dark" : "light")),
    }),
    []
  );

  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return [theme, colorMode];
};
```

I did installed all npm packages and all are working fine alone but in App.js they suddenly stopped showing me any graphs and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `SidebarComp` component is rendered on route `"/dashboard"`, and ***all*** of the links it is rendering link to root-level routes, e.g. `to="/dashboard"` (*this one is actually fine*), `to="/team"`, `to="/contacts"`, etc, but the routes they need to actually target are `"/dashboard"`, `"/dashboard/team"`, `"/dashboard/contacts"`, etc.

## Solution

Update the links to use the ***full*** absolute paths:

```
<Item
  title="Dashboard"
  to="/dashboard" // <-- complete absolute path from root
  icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />}
  selected={selected}
  setSelected={setSelected}
/>
<Item
  title="Manage Team"
  to="/dashboard/team" // <-- complete absolute path from root
  icon={<PeopleOutlinedIcon />}
  selected={selected}
  setSelected={setSelected}
/>
```

Or update the links to use local ***relative*** paths from the `"/dashboard"` route where the sidebar is rendered:

```
<Item
  title="Dashboard"
  to="." // <-- relative path from "/dashboard"
  icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />}
  selected={selected}
  setSelected={setSelected}
/>
<Item
  title="Manage Team"
  to="team" // <-- relative path from "/dashboard"
  // or to="./team"
  icon={<PeopleOutlinedIcon />}
  selected={selected}
  setSelected={setSelected}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Routes should be wrapped in either a BrowserRouter or a HashRouter in your index.js like this:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='team' element={<Team />} />
      ...rest of your routes
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Comment: If OP's code wasn't rendering a router component then it wouldn't run as there's an invariant check that would fail and throw an exception if this was the case. Since OP isn't mentioning any such error I highly doubt this is the case.